# My Milestone doesn't always charge

Tags: usb, charging, motorola-milestone

I have a Milestone and sometimes when I plug my (supplied Motorola) charger in the 'charging light' on the side does not illuminate and the phone does not charge. I think that this may also happen even after a successful initial connection (i.e. after plugging it in and getting the light) since occasionally I have unplugged the phone in the morning, after an overnight charge, and it is only 30% full (rather than the expected 100%).
This problem is intermittent and sometimes rights itself but other times I need to reboot the phone.
I have replaced the cable, and still have the same issue, so it is unlikely to be due to a faulty cable.
This happens both when charging it from a wall socket or a USB port.
Does anybody else have this problem? Or maybe have an idea of what it could be?

*edit:* Faulty hardware may be the cause... I have seen similar posts about people having intermittent problems connecting their Milestones to USB ports, so I'm curious that this may be either a generic bug or a generic hardware fault, rather than just my phone.

Answer (score 1):

May be possible that when plugging in your charger/usb cables it's not making a connection, I had a problem on an old phone (Nokia N95) with this and had to send it off for a new one.

Also possible that it may be the charger, have you got another you could try?

Comment: Yeah, I have actually tried it with another charger and it still didn't work. Faulty hardware may be the cause... I have seen similar posts about people having intermittent problems connecting their Milestones to USB ports, so I'm curious that this may be either a generic bug or a generic hardware fault, rather than just my phone.

Comment: I say sending it back is the best bet then. I hope this isn't an issue on the Milestone 2, I've got my eyes on one!

Answer (score 1):

I have a charger with a bad cable. It sometimes charges and sometimes it won't. Wiggling the cable point seems to help (don't do that though for risk of damaging your phone.

Check if its your cable or your phone by charging your phone with a data cable. If that charges your device your original charges is faulty. If this doesnt work either your phone connector is bad and you can either wiggle till it works or get a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes cables don't conform to standards and mess up the auto-negotiation of power level for the devices attached to them. (Devices can tell the computer / charger how much electricity they require). Phone can handle the max level of electricity, so soldering the 2nd and 3rd pins together on the cable will demand more power from the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any app killer? I used to use this kind of software, and sometimes I accidentally killed some system service and then it only charged again after a reboot.

I stopped using app killers after that.